# How to access a root attribute from a deeper level in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm calling a template:

```
<table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/pics/row"/>
</table>
```

The template is

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="td">
            <td border="0">
                <a href="{@referencddePage}">
                    <img src="{pic/@src}" width="{pic/@width}" height="{pic/@height}"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslFiles\smallPageBuilder.xsl"?>
<data pageNo="3" referencePage="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml">
    <pics>
        <row no="0">
            <td col="0">
                <pic src="A.jpg" width="150" height="120"></pic>
            </td>
        </row>
    </pics>
</data>
```

I want the line `:a     h r e f="{@referencddePage}"` to get the input from
 the root, `:a    h r e f= "{@referencddePage}"...`, but I'm already in the `<td level>`.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a solution that is both simple and completely in the spirit of XSLT, using predominantly "push style".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the line :a     h r e
>   f="{@referencddePage}" to get the
>   input from  the root :a    h r e f=
>   "{@referencddePage}"... but I'm
>   already in the `<td level>`

In case it is a rule that the `@referencePage` attribute is always an attribute of the top element, then it can always be accessed as:

```
/*/@referencePage
```

Therefore, in your code you'll have:

```
<a href="{/*/@referencePage}">
```

I would recommend not to use `<xsl:for-each>` and to use only `and``. In this way the resulting XSLT code is more understandable and can be more easily modified in the future:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="row">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="td">
   <td border="0">
     <a href="{/*/@referencePage}">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </a>
   </td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="pic">
   <img src="{@src}" width="{@width}" height="{@height}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document,

```
<data pageNo="3" referencePage="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml">
  <pics>
    <row no="0">
      <td col="0">
        <pic src="A.jpg" width="150" height="120"></pic>
      </td>
    </row>
  </pics>
</data>
```

the wanted output is produced:

```
<tr>
   <td border="0">
      <a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml">
         <img src="A.jpg" width="150" height="120"/>
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

See how each template is so very simple. Also, the code is further simplified.

Now, instead of:

```
   <img src="{pic/@src}" width="{pic/@width}" height="{pic/@height}"/>
```

we have only:

```
   <img src="{@src}" width="{@width}" height="{@height}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XPATH that "jumps" to the top of the document with a leading slash, then walk down the tree:

`/data/@referencePage`

Applying it to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <tr> 
        <xsl:for-each select="td"> 
            <td border="0">
                <a href="{/data/@referencePage}"> 
                    <img src="{pic/@src}" width="{pic/@width}" height="{pic/@height}"/> 
                </a>
            </td> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </tr> 
</xsl:template>
```